# MSMQ Quota Exceeded - Messages missing

Tags: msmq

We had a situation where we exceeded the quota limit in MSMQ. It appears that all messages in the queue are gone now though even though they haven't been delivered.

When i look at the performance counters for "MSMQ Queue" it indicates several hundred thousand messages in the "Computer Queues" "Messages in Queue". Are these the lost messages and how can i retrieve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are in one of the Dead letter Queues.